# Set stack limit permanently in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, stack

I need to increase the stack limit on Ubuntu 18.04 permanently, such that the new limit is in place for all users in all circumstances. Thus, setting in with `ulimit -s ...`, including in Bash profile and similar solutions, will not work for me. I tried:

- Setting the limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. This had no effect. I tried setting both hard and soft limits, for root and my user. Restarted. Nothing changes.
- Set `DefaultLimitSTACK=32768` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/systemd/user.conf`. 32768 is the desired stack limit in Kb. The window manager wouldn't load after restart, instead I was dropped into some kind of emergency root shell, where most commands segfaulted as well. I interpreted it as the stack limit being set to 32Kb instead of 32Mb as intended.
- Set `DefaultLimitSTACK=33554432` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/systemd/user.conf`. The system loads normally, `ulimit -s` still shows 8192, nothing changed.

Could someone advise how to make this work? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing a script(where you set the ulimit) in /etc/init.d/ directory.

Syntax of scripts in /etc/init.d/ - https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide//etc/init.d

These scripts are executed while switching on and off the system [Specific function is called for start and stop].

Comment: `ulimit` is a Bash command that will only set the limit for the current shell session and its children. So it can't work, because the shell that executes `init.d` scripts doesn't start all other processes. Or does it? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly systemd ignores parameters set in ulimits, see https://serverfault.com/a/678861

On my Ubuntu 18 system I'm using 16mb stack and set it in /etc/systemd:

```
user.conf:    DefaultLimitSTACK=16777216

system.conf:  DefaultLimitSTACK=16777216
```

- System restart or log out of the session for the new settings to take effect. You can then use `ulimit -s <value>` to set your stack for the user's shell session at or below the DefaultLimitStack.

Additionally you can add `ulimit -s 16384` into your user's **.bashrc** file. Then Each time its session is started the stack will be set to this desired value.